# MPI_Bcast c++ STL vector

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, stl, mpi

Why does the following code not work? It works for my user-defined class but not for STL vector.

```
std::vector<int> v(4);
MPI_Bcast(&v, sizeof(v), MPI_BYTE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

I got segmentation error:

```
[sdg:13611] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[sdg:13611] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
```

Since the elements in vector are stored contiguously, why can't I send std::vector as a whole using MPI_BYTE?

Comment: This question is frequently asked in numerous variations, but I haven't found a suitable duplicate. So I tried to add a canonical answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The address of a `vector` itself is not the same as of it's `data`. Sending objects like you propose only works for *trivially copyable* types - you can imagine MPI communication works similarly to `memcpy`. You can check with `std::is_trivially_copyable` - `std::vector` itself is never *trivially copyable*.

However, `vector` stores it's `data` in contiguous memory - on which you may use `memcpy`.

You must ensure that **all MPI processes have a vector with the same `size` before the operation**. `capacity` is not sufficient. If you only know the `size` on one process, you must broadcast the size before and `resize` the target vectors on the other process accordingly.

Also, the elements in your vector must be *trivially copyable* themselves.

```
MPI_Bcast(v.data(), v.size(), MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

If for some reason you have trouble figuring out the MPI type (e.g. `MPI_INT`), you can do it as follows (avoiding redundancy that breaks when you change the type).

```
MPI_Bcast(v.data(), v.size() * sizeof(decltype(v)::value_type)), MPI_BYTE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you want

```
if (!v.empty())
    MPI_Bcast(&v[0], v.size() * sizeof(decltype(v)::value_type)), MPI_BYTE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: Yes that would work. But I want to write a general function to Bcast any object. `MPI_Bcast(&foo, sizeof(foo), MPI_BYTE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD)` works for most classes I know, but not for std::vector.

Comment: This condition is a bad trap inviting errors where `v` is empty on some ranks.

Comment: Zulan: That is why the first line of code is checking to see if v is not empty and does not make the API call to MPI_Bcast if it is.

Comment: user27490: sizeof(foo) wont work. A vector typically is 3 pointers.  So for 32-bits you will get 12 and for 64-bits 24, regardless of how many items the vector is managing. The true size of the vector  is always v.size() * sizeof(underlying type)

Comment: @SJHowe `MPI_Bcast()` is a collective operation and hence must be invoked by all the ranks of the communicator. A direct consequence is that `v.size()` (and hence `v.empty()`) must be identical on all the ranks, and it is up to the programmer to ensure that. if `v` is empty on some but not all ranks, your app will likely end up hanging, possibly in an other location, making troubleshooting very hard.. On the other hand, if `v.size()` is not identical, your app will likely crash in `MPI_Bcast()` and that is way easier to debug.